# Is it possible to receive input data in firebase with a json request from a third party API?

Tags: firebase

Firebase should request realtime data from a third party API. The API response would be json. Is it possible to have an inbound API in firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a cloud function `https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/`

If you want a do something more complex you can build a microservice, and use Firebase Hosting